# Teams Bot SDK - Does the Channel Account ID ever change?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

When a user installs my Teams app, I store their Channel account ID in a database.

Later, I will use this same ID to get the conversation reference and send them a proactive message. This work correctly so far, for personal, group and team conversations.

I am wondering if this ID ever changes, or if it is unique to that bot / user / channel and will always remain the same.

[Link to Channel Account ID Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.channelaccount.id?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#microsoft-bot-schema-channelaccount-id)

Here is an example of me fetching the conversation reference, `contextId` is the Channel Account ID

```js
const conversationParameters: Partial<ConversationParameters> = {
    tenantId,
    members: [ { id: contextId, name: "", aadObjectId: aadId }],
    bot: { id: botId, name: "" },
};

await adapter.createConversationAsync(process.env.MicrosoftAppId, "msteams", serviceURL, null, conversationParameters as ConversationParameters,
    async context => {
         const ref = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
         ...
   }
})
```

Cheers

Comment: The Channel Account ID that you store in your database is unique to the combination of your bot, user, and channel. It will remain the same unless there are changes made to any of these components.

Comment: Thank you. When you mention bot, this is the bot service / app registration? What would count as a change that might affect this ID? Would updating the permissions on the bot's app registration cause the ID to change, or is the Channel Account ID linked to the bot/app ID and will only change if the bot was replaced with a entirely new bot. Cheers

Comment: It will change if it is replaced with an entirely new bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided in comments by Meghana-MSFT

> The Channel Account ID that you store in your database is unique to the combination of your bot, user, and channel. It will remain the same unless there are changes made to any of these components.